# Can't find FaceRecognizer in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV with C++ attempting to create a facial recognition program.
In a lot of tutorials I see they use cv::FaceRecognizer. I can't find this anywhere? It does not appear to be in my version of OpenCV? (3.4.1)

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

I have this include which gives me access to the rest of cv:: .. but I cannot locate this class. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You need include face.hpp

```
#include "opencv2/face.hpp"
```

You also need to use the face namespace:

```
using namespace cv::face;
```

and ensure that you have compiled the `opencv_contrib` module

Make sure you read [the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/face/doc/facerec/index.html) which include lots of code samples, if you can run those you can run anything!

Comment: opencv2/face.hpp doesn't appear in my list of available includes, how do i compile the opencv_contrib module please?

Comment: @NathanHeadley there are ample tutorials you should find with a google search. Without knowing your system/setup details it wouldn't make sense for me to recommend one.